# How to select a column value based on two text string filter criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a column that contains a list of alphanumeric codes, and I'm trying to select all where there is not **both** a "1" and an "I" in the same value.

In the sample here, the last value would be filtered out of the results

```
Code  
0KESB  
A6H6M  
4JSYP  
13I7P - X
```

I don't want to just use `WHERE code NOT LIKE '%1%' and NOT LIKE '%I%`, because that'll exclude any "1" or "I" and it's really just the two together that are a problem.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
WHERE NOT (code LIKE '%1%' AND code LIKE '%I%')
```

See [this example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69502/2).

An alternative would be to use a regular expression with the `regexp` operator.